# Unescaped Attribute Value XSS in Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, content-security-policy

Salesforce ran SonarQube Code Quality on my org and there were several errors like 'Unescaped Attribute Value XSS' in the aura components. All these errors occur in component elements that call the controller, see examples below:

```
<lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion"  onsectiontoggle="{!c.onloadDisplayOtherField}">



<lightning:radioGroup name="{!doc.labelRadioGroup}" label=""
                                                required="false" options="{!doc.optionsRadioGroup}" value="{!doc.value}"
                                                type="radio" onchange="{!c.onchangeDisplayOtherField}"
                                                aura:id="radioSelect" />



<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Swap clause" title="swap" onclick="{!c.swapClause }" disabled="{!v.swapDisable}"/>
```

I've searched extensively on how to solve this problem but haven't found a solution. As far as I know there is no other way to call the controller and no treatment to be done about it. Has anyone gone through this and can help?

Comment: Your Aura Components are being evaluated as Visualforce or something like that. This is either a problem with how your files are organized, or a bug in the software. These are definitely not valid examples of XSS in Aura.

Comment: Exactly. I scoured the internet and didn't find anything that had a relationship between XSS and Aura in these scenarios. Thanks!